# What is the most pythonic way to map two different strings, to act as one?

Tags: python

#### The problem

Imagine two services running:

Service 1 has two statuses: `ACTIVE/INACTIVE`

Service 2 has two statuses: `RUNNING/TERMINATED`

We want to do a simple status comparison as:

```
service1_status = get_service2_status()
service2_status = get_service2_status()

if service1_status == service2_status:
   // They match!
else:
   // They don't match!
```

---

#### A working solution

This is a relatively simple task of course. A working solution would be something like this:

```
service1_status = get_service2_status()
service2_status = get_service2_status()

if service1_status == 'ACTIVE' and service2_status == 'RUNNING':
   return "They match!"
elif service1_status == 'INACTIVE' and service2_status == 'TERMINATED':
   return "They match!"
else:
   return "They don't match!"
```

---

#### The problem - but more difficult

Now imagine this example a hundred different statuses for each service instead of two.

The if statement would be overwhelming. I am looking for a more elegant way to program this. e.g:

```
matching_tuples = [('x1', 'y1'), ('x2', 'y2'), ..., ('x100', 'y100')]

service1_status = get_service2_status()
service2_status = get_service2_status()

if (service1_status, service2_status) in matching_tuples:
   return "They match!"
elif:
   return "They don't match!"
```

This works and is fine. I wonder though if there is a better, more pythonic and elegant way to marry two strings together and compare them.

Comment: If you want to *map* strings – use a mapping, i.e. a ``dict``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also have to map keys from the backend and frontend.
For mapping, I usually use a `dictionary` you can add as many keys as you want like this.

```
MapService1to2 = {
    "ACTIVE": "RUNNING",
    "INACTIVE": "TERMINATED"
}

service1_status = get_service2_status()
service2_status = get_service2_status()

if MapService1to2[service1_status] == service2_status:
    print("They match")
else:
    print("They don't match")
```

Answer (score 2):

Decide on a base-line service and map its statuses to the other:

```py
service1_status = get_service2_status()
service2_status = get_service2_status()

mapping = {"ACTIVE": "RUNNING", "INACTIVE": "TERMINATED"}

if mapping[service1_status] == service2_status:
   return "They match!"
else:
   return "They don't match!"
```

In case a status of service1 might not be mapped, you can choose either to:

1. Raise the `KeyError` (as above, using `mapping[service1_status]`).
2. Silence the error by using `mapping.get(service1_status)` instead and treat it as "no match".
3. Catch the error and re-raise it as an informative debugging message:

   ```py
   try:
       match = mapping[service1_status] == service2_status
   except KeyError:
       raise KeyError(f"The status {service1_status} of service1 is not mapped to any status in service2")
   ```

---

Depending on your actual input, you might not need to construct the dict manually:

- If you already have something like your provided `matching_tuples`, you can pass that directly to the dict constructor - `mapping = dict(matching_tuples)`.
- If you have two matching lists of the statuses you can do `mapping = dict(zip(statuses1, statuses2))` (Note that basically `matching_tuples = list(zip(statuses1, statuses2))`)